# How appropriate is "拜拜"?

Tags: taiwan, politeness, loanwords, informal

How appropriate, in terms of casualness and/or childishness, is "拜拜"? Is it as childish as "Bye-bye" would be in English, or is it more acceptable?

In case location matters, I'm mainly interested in how it's viewed in Taiwan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

拜拜 is not casualness and/or childishness,it is a more friendly way to express goodbye ,and majority use between people who have good relation,or see somebody for the first time and build a friendship each other.
So does it in Taiwan I think:)

Comment: And it applies to Hong Kong too. As ah_hau said 再见 or 再会 is more formal than 拜拜 but none of them are childish as in English.

Answer (score 2):

拜拜 is not considered childish, but is more casual than other forms of good-bye.  It can be use on children / friends / even seniors, but should not be use for Clients / business partner / etc.

Answer (score 0):

is bye bye consider childish? then formal 1 would be : good bye?

拜拜 got another meaning as praying.

http://www.123chickensoup.com/Upload/images.jpg

and more formal replacement would be : 再见 or 再会 which closer to see you again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's childish in Taiwan,at least not in TV.